# How to use project dependencies with ts-node

Tags: node.js, typescript, yarnpkg, ts-node

I am currently debugging a project that uses [`ts-node`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node) to run locally. Do I have to install `ts-node` globally for this?

I did install it globally, but now i am seeing typescript errors that stems from diverging typescript versions. I fixed it by setting it to the same version.

Is there a way to use my project dependencies in my CLI to run the project? Or do I HAVE to install things globally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the `node_modules` folder has a `.bin` subdirectory. You can run the local version of `ts-node` while in the project directory.

Here's what you might type into your shell

```sh
cd /path/to/project
./node_modules/.bin/ts-node myFile.ts
```

Comment: I think using local dependencies, as described on this answer, is preferable to keep your dev environment predictable

Answer (score 2):

Since [npm@5.2.0](https://github.com/npm/npm/releases/tag/v5.2.0), npm ships with the `npx` package, which lets you run commands from the `node_modules/.bin` directory in your current project. For example: `npx ts-node -v`.

If for whatever reason you have an older version of npm, you can install this package globally with `npm install -g npx`.

You can use `npx <package-name>` also for packages that aren't installed yet in your project (see [its options](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx#description)).

Alternatively, you can put the following into your `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "ts-node code/start.ts",
}
```

Commands in the `scripts` field also use the local version of a package.